# okhttp arraycopy is inaccessible to class 'okio.Buffer'

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to integrate okhttp in my code to upload large zip files to a server.
with android R, getting below exception.
any help would be appreciated

05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void java.lang.System.arraycopy(byte[], int, byte[], int, int)' is inaccessible to class 'okio.Buffer' (declaration of 'okio.Buffer' appears in /system/priv-app/..)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:943)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:931)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:47)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBuilder.java:241)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.contentLength(MultipartBuilder.java:220)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:244)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
05-13 15:20:21.479  1684  7741 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)

code used to upload file :

```
public void OkHttpUpload(String fileName, String target, String url){
    MediaType ZIP = MediaType.parse("application/zip");
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart(fileName, fileName, RequestBody.create(ZIP, new File(target)))
            .build();
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)                    
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new CloneOutOkHttp2Callback());
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Really surprising crash. Does it occur on all Android devices? Are you using ProGuard or R8?